# Jasmine: testing method called from window scope function

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine to te test some of my code. It looks a bit like this

```
# main logic
function Analytics() {
  this.construct = function() {
  }

  this.foo = function() {
  }

  this.bar = function() {
  }
}

# "main" routine, called by jQuery on ready, or direct by Jasmine
function analytics() {
  new Analytics().construct();
}

# calls main routine
$(document).ready(function () {
  analytics();
});
```

When running this in the browser, it works fine. However, when I want to test my code with Jasmine (test if the constructor gets called when calling analytics() it fails.

```
Expected spy construct to have been called. (1)
```

This is what the spec looks like:

```
it('should call the constructor when the document is ready', function({
    var _analytics = new Analytics();
    spyOn(_analytics, 'construct')
    analytics();  # note this is the "main" routine
    expect(_analytics.construct).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

My testcase seems to be incorrect but I don't really see how. Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As I see, from code "analytics" function creates new instance of Analytics.

So probably test works like that:

```
it('should call the constructor when the document is ready', function({
    var _analytics = new Analytics(); // --> create new instance of Analytics
    spyOn(_analytics, 'construct') // --> spy on construct func
    analytics();  // --> This, creates new instance
    // of analytics which you don't spy on.
    expect(_analytics.construct).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Try to spy via prototype:

```
spyOn(Analytics.prototype, 'construct'); // will spy all instances.
```

And test will look like this:

```
it('should call the constructor when the document is ready', function({
    spyOn(Analytics.prototype, 'construct');
    analytics();
    expect(Analytics.prototype.construct).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Note that you don't have access to instance created in analytics function.

You will be not able to use it after creation.

I don't know the context of the task. But maybe you should use default constructor.

```
function Analytics(options) {
   // this is constructor
   this.prop1 = options.prop1;
   this.prop2 = options.prop2;

   this.foo = function() {

   }

   this.bar = function() {

   }
}

var analyticsModule = new Analytics(options);
```